# How add all arrays to one in rxjs

Tags: angular, rxjs

how i can add all arrays to one in rxjs for this code?

```
someObs$ = this.getSomeData$().pipe(
    mergeMap(res => res),
    groupBy(el => el.class),
    mergeMap(group$ => group$.pipe(toArray())),
    // how in this place create something like this: [[{},{}], [{},{}], [{},{}]]
    shareReplay(1)
  )
```

Thanks for help

Comment: Can you share how your input data looks like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found solution for this: operator `toArray()`

Answer (score 0):

RxJS Doc definition of **[toArray](https://rxjs.dev/api/operators/toArray)** operator:

> **toArray** will wait until the source Observable completes before emitting the array containing all emissions. When the source
> Observable errors no array will be emitted.

Marble Diagram:
[image]